# How to get sum of rows and column in python pandas using some conditions

Tags: python, pandas

```
A B      C         D    E  E   G  H
0 US   BENIN      1995  5  10  15 40
1                 1996  6  12  12 12
2                 1997  4  13  12 12
3      Hungary    1995  5  19  23 23
4                 1999  3  23  12 34
```

1. How to get a total of column E F G H based on column C in pandas
2. How to get a total of column E F G H based on Column D in pandas

Comment: please share what you have tried. also add what is your desire output table.

Comment: Take a look at ```groupby``` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#splitting-an-object-into-groups

Comment: With pandas you have a couple functions to help you out.

To check if something is null you can use `np.where`
 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-where-in-python/

and pandas has a sum function 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-sum/

Comment: 1.
`data.groupby(['C'])[['E','F','G','H']].sum()`
2.
`data.groupby(['D'])[['E','F','G','H']].sum()`

Comment: It worked using group by. Thank you everyone.